# I am exporting to a flat file using SSIS. Why do some of my columns contain the result and 4 decimal places?

Tags: ssis

I am new to using Visual Studio. I have my data goin to a flat file.
There are 4 columns, all numerical values and 1 date.

2 of the numerical values keep exporting to the file as #.0000

What do I need to do to get the export to keep the whole value? NO decimals

Again being new, I tried changing the value type but couldn't figure it out.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak8ti.png)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the steps in your DataFlow and the exact data types used in your source and destination functoids. As a rule of thumb, usually the source dictates the data type and you'll to explicitly convert to a different data type (like `DT_I4` integer). Inspect your source using right-click to *Advanced edit...* and examine the external source columns and their data types.

Comment: I attached some photos . You can see the sql pulls the correct way but the file created has the extra 0's

Comment: The images are good start to improving the question. So you've got an Oracle? source based on the `to_char` call for column 3.  How is the `ATT_CODE_` column defined in Oracle? If you double click the connection between the ADO.NET Source and the Flat File Destination, on the Metadata tab, what does it list for the data type there for ATT_CODE_... column? Finally, in the `Flat File Connection Manager 2` what is specified for this column (Not the destination but in the actual CM)?

Comment: Check the last photo I uploaded regarding the meta

Answer (score 0):

When configuring your destination flat file, make sure that both column data types (SchoolID, ATT_CODE) is one of the integer-type data in your Flat File Connection Manager, DT_I4 as in the below picture:

[image: DERD]

Then go back to your source to preview data:

[image: DATEEEEE]

After running package, EndResult:

[image: End_Result]